# record modification date of a value - laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to create a function that records the date a field was updated.

Right now I have the code to update, but I don't know how to register a change and save a date.

I thought to use `Carbon::now()`, but how do I save the value in a table?

```
  public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $nuevoIngreso = \App\Models\Registro::find($id);
    $nuevoIngreso->anticipo = $request->anticipo;
    $nuevoIngreso->save();

    return redirect('sistema')->with('mensaje', 'Ficha Actualizada.');
}
```

Comment: Whenever you update Eloquent record, it automatically saves the current timestamp into the updated_at column

Comment: If it's not updated, use $nuevoIngreso->update(['updated_at' => now()]); or just $nuevoIngreso->touch();

Comment: I understand that it saves changes in the updated_at column, but I want to save only the date of the variable: 
$nuevoIngreso->anticipo = $request->anticipo;

Comment: What do you mean you only want to save the date of the variable ? You want to store the new variable and save when it was changed ? or does that variable hold a `date` as a value and you want to save that value in that DB field ? (I speak spanish, so I know that anticipo means how much money you are paying before fully paying)

Comment: I want to store the new variable and save when it was modified